# jQuery ajax post generates "Unexpected token : [newline]" on JSON response from Node + Express

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, express

jQuery ajax post generates an errror "Unexpected token : [newline]" on JSON response from Node + Express:

```
SyntaxError {stack: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token :↵    at eval (nativ…st:3000/javascripts/jquery-1.10.1.min.js:6:18626)", message: "Unexpected token :"}
```

On the server:

```
app.post('/api/sav', function(req, res, next) {
  var result = {"status": "success"};        
    res.send(JSON.stringify(result))  // this works

    //res.type('json');  // this has no effect  
    //res.type('application/json');  // this has no effect      
    //res.send(result); // this fails but should work, no?
    //res.json(result); // this fails but should work, no?
});
```

And on the client

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: '/api/sav',
     data: content,
     success: function(data, textStatus, jqXhr) {
       console.log(data);
     },
     error: function(jqXHR, textStatus,errorThrown ) {
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
     },
     dataType: 'json'
 });
```

The server response seems identical in each case:
[image]

In the past, I've been able to use `res.send(object)` just fine without explicitly stringifying.  Can't think of any express.js settings that I've forgotten to set here.

[syntax error: unexpected token <](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18561556/syntax-error-unexpected-token)

Comment: you're really mixing apples and oranges. the ajax request is going to `/api/sav` but the node code has `/api/myroute`. you also didn't mention what `content` is in your ajax request. when I pasted the code into sublimetext, sublimelinter picked up that there's a trailing whitespace on the line with `var result = {"status": "success"};` which could possibly be the problem if the ajax request was actually reaching `/api/myroute`. I hope that helps