# asp mvc display not updating when using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have been following the example of some ajax functionality I got working earlier in my project, but I have come to a sticking point where my current functionality doesn't seem to work, the only difference that I can see that I am naming the `partialView` that I am returning and that I am trying to update images being displayed (although i'm guessing that wont make a difference).

**Aim**
Allow user to select and upload images, and display newly uploaded images using ajax

**Problem**
Images from both the temporary and final destination folders are displayed on initial page load, but partial page refresh does not appear to happen after upload is complete

controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult _Image(TakeOn to, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> FileUpload)
{
    to.ImageUpload(FileUpload);//takes all files in FileUpload and places them in a temporary folder
    return PartialView("_Rooms", to);
}
```

js (ajax)

```
$(".row").on("change", ".imgInput", function (e) {
    var roomID = $(this).siblings("input:hidden").val();
    $("#roomIdentifier").val(roomID);
    var formData = new FormData(jQuery('#takeOn').get(0)) // store form data to pass on to the controller
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Property/_Image",
        contentType: false,
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        encode: true,
        async: false,
        processData: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            //$(".imgUploader").html(data);//first attempt, both tried by targetting .imgUploader and #accordion
            $("#accordion").replaceWith(("#accordion", html));
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
        }
    });

    //clear input value
    var input = $(this);
    input.replaceWith(input.val('').clone(true));
    //clear identifier
    $("#roomIdentifier").val('');
});
```

view (_Rooms.cshtml) - (this is a partial view which is held in `#accordion` div )

```
@model TjsPropertyPeople.Web.Admin.ViewModels.Property.TakeOn

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Rooms.Count; i++)
{
<div class="panel panel-default room">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            @{ ViewBag.Title = Model.Rooms[i].Title == null ? "New Room" : Model.Rooms[i].Title; }
            @{ ViewBag.titleID = "title" + i; }
            <a id=@ViewBag.titleID data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" class="collapsed">@ViewBag.Title</a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse collapse in" style="height: auto;">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <row class="col-lg-4">
                @{ViewBag.roomID = "roomtitle" + i;}
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Rooms[i].Title, null, new { @id = ViewBag.roomID, @class = "form-control roomTitle", @placeholder = "Title" })
            </row>
            <row class="col-lg-4">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Rooms[i].Width, null, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Width" })
            </row>
            <row class="col-lg-4">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Rooms[i].Length, null, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Length" })
                <label class="checkbox-inline">
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.Rooms[i].Overall) Overall
                </label>
            </row>
            <row class="col-lg-6">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Rooms[i].Description, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Description" })
            </row>
            <row class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="imgUploader">
                    <div>
                        <div style="height: auto; width: auto; position: relative;">
                            @{ ViewBag.TempPath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Uploads/Images/Temp/" + Model.PropertyID + "/" + Model.Rooms[i].RoomID + "/"); }
                            @{ ViewBag.UploadedPath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Uploads/Images/Property/" + Model.PropertyID + "/" + Model.Rooms[i].RoomID + "/"); }
                            @{ ViewBag.TempExists = Directory.Exists(ViewBag.TempPath); }
                            @{ ViewBag.UploadedExists = Directory.Exists(ViewBag.UploadedPath); }
                            @{ List<string> files = new List<string>(); }

                            @if (ViewBag.TempExists)
                            {
                                string[] f = Directory.GetFiles(ViewBag.TempPath);
                                files.AddRange(f);
                            }
                            @if (ViewBag.UploadedExists)
                            {
                                string[] f = Directory.GetFiles(ViewBag.UploadedPath);
                                files.AddRange(f);
                            }
                            @foreach (var file in files)
                            {
                                string name = file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf("App_Uploads"));
                                name = @"~\" + name;
                                <img class="pull-left panel" src="@Url.Content(name)" height="50" />
                                @*<div class="delete">X</div>*@
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input class="imgInput" type="file" name="FileUpload" multiple accept="image/jpeg">
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Rooms[i].RoomID)
            </row>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

**Note**
I realise that the view could be written MUCH better, I just don't know how to abstract all that unnecessary code from the view at this time and feel I should get the functionality working before "playing" with yet another area I don't fully understand (although I'm against any advice that can be offered in this area)

**EDIT**

in the error part of the script I added `alert("Error: " + error)` and it returned this

`javascript error syntax: unexpected token <`

I have googled it and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18561556/syntax-error-unexpected-token), there seem to be a lot of places in my code that could be causing this (if this answer is applicable to me). So how would I start tracking down the root of the problem?

Comment: Any errors? Is the partial in the same folder as the view or in the shared folder?

Comment: No errors are being thrown that ive seen (nothing in code and nothin in the console) The partial is in the same folder

Comment: Is this your comment here: "//first attempt, both tried by targetting .imgUploader and #accordion"? You are saying $('#accordion').html(data) did not work for you?

Comment: yes. ive tried `.imgUploader` and `#accordion` on bothlines. I try your suggestion to see if any errors occour and post my findings

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line in your `$ajax.success` function from:

```
$("#accordion").replaceWith(("#accordion", html));
```

To:

```
 $("#accordion").html(data);
```

The `("#accordion", html)` looks like invalid jQuery to me, and I don't see a var called `html` in your code either. Your partial HTML response var is named `data` not `html`.

If that doesn't work, add the following line to your $ajax.success function:

```
console.log(data);
```

And see that the response is your Partial HTML in your browser F12 developer tools `Console`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Brian Ogden I was able to resolve this issue.

As mentioned I needed to change

`$("#accordion").replaceWith(("#accordion", html));`

To:

`$("#accordion").html(data);`

But this brought another problem `syntax error: unexpected token <`

It was caused by not closing a html tag so changing:

`<input class="imgInput" type="file" name="FileUpload" multiple accept="image/jpeg">`

to

`<input class="imgInput" type="file" name="FileUpload" multiple accept="image/jpeg" />`

resolved it completely. I would be interested to know why a badly formatted tag stop ajax calls from working

Comment: It wasn't a badly formatted tag that stopped your Ajax call, your Ajax call was successful, check by adding the bad markup format back, and adding a console.log('ajax.success called'); to your $ajax.success function. The unexpected token error is thrown by jQuery, the jQuery you call in your $ajax.success function when your HTML markup has an invalid closing tag.

Comment: Also, your answer here really isn't appropriate as the answer to your question is my answer, this "unexpected token" error is a new error and could be a new SO question but I think you will find that my previous comment explains how your Ajax does not care if your HTML markup is valid or not, its jQuery that threw the exeception