# jquery Convert String to Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to create a JSON object from a string in the correct JSON format I received from my .jsp file. 
I get the string and convert it as follows:

```
try{
        var jsonStringer = JSON.stringify(mazeFromServer);
        var obj = JSON.parse(jsonStringer);
    }catch (e){
        window.alert(e);
    }
```

This works without errors. 
When I try to manipulate or get information from that object, for instance:

```
var stringName = obj.Name;
```

Although i have a Name field in my JSON, nothing happens. 
I checked my JSON on the JSON validation website and everything was fine. 
What is wrong?

JSON looks like this:

```
{
        "Name": "Game1",
        "Level":"Two"};
```

When I declare JSON by myself, it works fine. But when I receive it in a String format from an outside source it doesn't work.

Any Ideas?

EDIT:

mazeFromServer is a string received from an external server.
In my servlet i am adding it as follows:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("progress", fromServer);
```

And then running this Query in my jsp file:

```
function getMaze(){
    $.getJSON("ProgressServlet", function(data){
        if (data.progress != current)
                mazeFromServer = data.progress;
            $('.mazeLabel').text(mazeFromServer);
        stopJSONCheck();
    })
}
```

The mazeFromServer Looks as follows:

```
{
```

"Name": "Game1",
  "Maze": "111111111110000000",
  "Start": {
    "Row": 3,
    "Col": 3
  },
  "End": {
    "Row": 1,
    "Col": 3
  }
}

Comment: please replace JSON object with object. [JSON](http://json.org/) is always a string.

Comment: What is in `mazeFromServer` and why do you `stringify` it?

Comment: What you mean by JSON string??

Comment: @MysterX mazeFromServer is the JSON that I I received by using the 
$.getJSON call.

Comment: JSON is a serialized object (after serialization it's a string) with special notation. an object is just an object.

Comment: You're stringifying something which is already a string, then unstringifying the results.  Skip the first step.

Comment: Yeah, get rid of `var jsonStringer = JSON.stringify(mazeFromServer);` and change the obj line to `var obj = JSON.parse(mazeFromServer);`

Comment: Have you tried:  alert(typeof obj);

Comment: This question is tagged as jQuery (though no jQuery code is shown). That library will normally convert from/to JSON automatically in many circumstances so you'll probably get better answers if you provide some context.

Comment: If I don't use stringify it throws me an exception "Unexpected Token"

Comment: @SPlatten yes, it tells me that it is a String

Comment: In that case you can't get .Name from it as it isn't an object.

Comment: Using the browsers console window is extremely helpful. Adding a line `console.log(mazeFromServer);` to see what mazeFromServer actually looks like would be really helpful to see if it's already an object or not. That will tell you way more, way faster, about the variable.

Comment: And what if you just use `var stringName = mazeFromServer.Name`???

Comment: @Anialation the Console.log shows me what the Object looks like in the correct form

Comment: Wait.  If you're using `$.getJSON` to get `mazeFromServer`, jQuery should be doing the parsing for you -- you should neither need to `.stringify` nor `.parse` the results -- just use `mazeFromServer` as is.  Have you tried `mazeFromServer.Name`?

Comment: Yes i tried writing
var name = mazeFromServer.Name; and still does not draw the Name

Comment: And what happened?

Comment: Nothing. 
var name = mazeFromServer.Name;
$('.nameLabel').text(name);
Nothing in the label changes

Comment: @user2955610 if the console log specifically said the item was an object, then you should be good to go. Try `console.log(mazeFromServer.Name);`. If that works, then your problem is somewhere else in your code. If not, you may still need the `JSON.parse(mazeFromServer);`.

Comment: @user2955610 
The console shows me:
Uncaught ReferenceError: Name is not defined

Comment: @user2955610 Then try: `var obj = JSON.parse(mazeFromServer); console.log(obj.Name);`

Comment: Console Output: 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Comment: That error message indicates that what you're trying to parse isn't in fact JSON.  What does `console.log(typeof(mazeFromServer))` result in? And what are the *exact* contents of `mazeFromServer`?  Is there any chance it includes a header, or some other value, along with the JSON (as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18561556/syntax-error-unexpected-token)?)

Comment: @user2955610 It looks like your JSON data has a `;` at the end. I thought I tested for that when checking it out but I guess my IDE filtered it out. That can't be there.

Comment: @Anialation it doesnt, where did you see that?

Comment: @Anialation Even if i try after that call eg:
 $.getJSON("ProgressServlet", function(data){
            if (data.progress != current)
                    mazeFromServer = data.progress;
                $('.mazeLabel').text(mazeFromServer.Name);
This doesnt change the label

Comment: @user2955610 So right before `$('.mazeLabel').text(mazeFromServer.Name);` add a console log for `mazeFromServer` and `mazeFromServer.Name` and see what happens. If those fail, try `mazeFromServer = JSON.parse(data.progress);` and see what the console logs give you.

Comment: console.log(mazeFromServer) Shows we all the contents of the object in its correct form
console.log(mazeFromServer.Name) shows "underfined"

Comment: What exactly does `console.log(mazeFromServer)` say though? If it's a proper object, it should look like this (depending on browser): `Object {Name: "Game1", Level: "Two"}`. It needs to say `Object` at the begining. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/qvne2c7w/)

Comment: It doesnt say object next to it

Comment: {
  "Name": "Game1",
  "Maze": "111111110010010101000000000",
  "Start": {
    "Row": 3,
    "Col": 3
  },
  "End": {
    "Row": 1,
    "Col": 3
  }
}

Comment: @user2955610 So it's not an object yet and you'll need the like `mazeFromServer = JSON.parse(data.progress);`

Comment: Can't do that, it wont accept the type

Comment: Then I'm not sure, we're missing something but I'm not sure what. Also, are you sure `if (data.progress != current)` is triggering correctly? You could do a `console.log(data.progress != current);` to check

Answer (score 1):

You should modify your code as follows:

```
    try{
        var obj;

        if ( typeof mazeFromServer != "string" ) {
            obj = jsonStringer;
        } else {
            var jsonStringer = JSON.stringify(mazeFromServer);

            if ( typeof jsonStringer != "string" ) {
                throw("mazeFromServer cannot be converted to JSON string");
            }   
            obj = JSON.parse(jsonStringer);
        }
        if ( typeof obj != "object" ) {
            throw("'obj' is not an object, it is: " + typeof obj);
        }
    } catch (e) {
        window.alert(e);
    }
```

Comment: It throws: "Cannot JSON string back to object"

Comment: Can you post the content of mazeFromServer plz?  Try the insertion I posted above before calling stringify.

Comment: Throws: "mazeFromServer is not an object"

Comment: Modified again, might give you some clue.

Comment: Throws: mazeFromServer is not an object, it is: string

Comment: There you go, thats your problem.  If you have outer quotes around the data, remove them.

Comment: You mean remove all the quoatation marks in the entire string?

Comment: You don't need quotes around the outer string or around the data labels.  Just around data string values, e.g {label:"data"}, but make sure any quotes are escaped,if building a string of JSON {label:\"data\"}

Comment: But that is how I am receiving the string from the outer server. I don't know what the fields are. I cant just remove all the quotes then

Comment: If you are receiving a string then why convert are you treating is as an object?  You only call stringify to convert an object to a string...you can miss this bit out.

Comment: Receiving it as a string but need to extract the fields from it. I thought the best would be to treat is as an object then i would be able to extract fields eg:
mazeFromServer.Name

Comment: Should jsonStringer have been initialized before?
it throws: "obj is not an object"

Comment: Modified again to display actual type.

Comment: I would use a browser with a debug facility, set a breakpoint on the JSON.parse line then single step and watch the data, it should be very obvious what is going on.