# 'npm run build' gives me uncaught syntax error: Unexpected token '<' when I try to render the html file for my single page react app

Tags: reactjs

[Here is what the package structure looks. Server folder contains the flask code, the src folder contains react code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StLis.png)

I have a Flask server with a react app. When I run the npm build script, it builds the 'build' folder. When flask attempts to render the html for my react app, I get the error for the Unexpected token '<' for 2.ed52de7f.chunk.js. It seems rather simple, but I have been stuck on this for a while and I desperately need help. The app renders fine when I open it using 'npm run start'.

Comment: How did you set up your package.json?

Comment: I basically create-react-scripts and downloaded a a few other dependencies using npm install *package name*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [syntax error: unexpected token <](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18561556/syntax-error-unexpected-token)

Answer (score 1):

> Unexpected token '<' for 2.ed52de7f.chunk.js

This means the request to get the static js file returns a HTML instead of javascript. You can do following things:

- Check the url of chunk.js again, make sure it point to correct server
- Trying to request that js with its url you will figure out the error

Hope this help