# 67:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON P

Tags: javascript, reactjs, miragejs

I'm doing a tutorial from scrimba for react and react router 6 and I'm encountering an error with the provided data. The error says `67:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON P` and is at line 9 which is `.then(data => setVans(data.vans))`. The whole code for `Vans.jsx` is:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

export default function Vans() {
    const [vans, setVans] = React.useState([])
    React.useEffect(() => {
        fetch("/api/vans")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => setVans(data.vans))
    }, [])

    const vanElements = vans.map(van => (
        <div key={van.id} className="van-tile">
            <Link to={`/vans/${van.id}`}>
                <img src={van.imageUrl} />
                <div className="van-info">
                    <h3>{van.name}</h3>
                    <p>${van.price}<span>/day</span></p>
                </div>
                <i className={`van-type ${van.type} selected`}>{van.type}</i>
            </Link>
        </div>
    ))

    return (
        <div className="van-list-container">
            <h1>Explore our van options</h1>
            <div className="van-list">
                {vanElements}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The data from the api is coming from `server.js` which is:

```js
import { createServer, Model } from "miragejs"


createServer({
    models: {
        vans: Model,
    },

    seeds(server) {
        server.create("van", { id: "1", name: "Modest Explorer", price: 60, description: "The Modest Explorer is a van designed to get you out of the house and into nature. This beauty is equipped with solar panels, a composting toilet, a water tank and kitchenette. The idea is that you can pack up your home and escape for a weekend or even longer!", imageUrl: "https://assets.scrimba.com/advanced-react/react-router/modest-explorer.png", type: "simple" })
        server.create("van", { id: "2", name: "Beach Bum", price: 80, description: "Beach Bum is a van inspired by surfers and travelers. It was created to be a portable home away from home, but with some cool features in it you won't find in an ordinary camper.", imageUrl: "https://assets.scrimba.com/advanced-react/react-router/beach-bum.png", type: "rugged" })
        server.create("van", { id: "3", name: "Reliable Red", price: 100, description: "Reliable Red is a van that was made for travelling. The inside is comfortable and cozy, with plenty of space to stretch out in. There's a small kitchen, so you can cook if you need to. You'll feel like home as soon as you step out of it.", imageUrl: "https://assets.scrimba.com/advanced-react/react-router/reliable-red.png", type: "luxury" })
        server.create("van", { id: "4", name: "Dreamfinder", price: 65, description: "Dreamfinder is the perfect van to travel in and experience. With a ceiling height of 2.1m, you can stand up in this van and there is great head room. The floor is a beautiful glass-reinforced plastic (GRP) which is easy to clean and very hard wearing. A large rear window and large side windows make it really light inside and keep it well ventilated.", imageUrl: "https://assets.scrimba.com/advanced-react/react-router/dreamfinder.png", type: "simple" })
        server.create("van", { id: "5", name: "The Cruiser", price: 120, description: "The Cruiser is a van for those who love to travel in comfort and luxury. With its many windows, spacious interior and ample storage space, the Cruiser offers a beautiful view wherever you go.", imageUrl: "https://assets.scrimba.com/advanced-react/react-router/the-cruiser.png", type: "luxury" })
        server.create("van", { id: "6", name: "Green Wonder", price: 70, description: "With this van, you can take your travel life to the next level. The Green Wonder is a sustainable vehicle that's perfect for people who are looking for a stylish, eco-friendly mode of transport that can go anywhere.", imageUrl: "https://assets.scrimba.com/advanced-react/react-router/green-wonder.png", type: "rugged" })
    },

    routes() {
        this.namespace = "api"

        this.get("/vans", (schema, request) => {
            return schema.vans.all()
        })
        
        this.get("/vans/:id", (schema, request) => {
            const id = request.params.id
            return schema.vans.find(id)
        })
    }
})
```

I've copied and pasted the code from the tutorial but is still getting the error. Anyone know what I'm missing here?

Comment: Your code is expecting JSON to be returned, but it's HTML that's being returned instead. You should inspect the result to find out what it says.

Comment: I tried to `console.log()` but no data is being returned.

Comment: Did you console.log `data.vans`? Here is a similiar question, but it comes down to some function expecting JSON data, but you are using HTML data. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18561556/syntax-error-unexpected-token

Comment: I did but now it shows `data` is not defined despite defining it in the function

Comment: You defined `vans` in your API server.js. But that is no guarantee your API call returned it. The next thing you should do is inspect the API response in the F12 console. Also inspect the value of `res` because if your API returns a HTML page with an error (instead of JSON) then you try and convert that response to json with `res.json()`, that would explain your error message. We are basically incrementally debugging by comment here. It is important that you learn how to debug and pull a problem apart into pieces and inspect every setp  of the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running this on your local right? I had the same issue. The problem was an import in the index.jsx file.

On Scrimba, they have `import "./server"`
I had to simply add a dot `import "../server"` because the local react build put the index.jsx file in the src folder.